# Friction in interstellar space

Tags: interstellar-medium

I wonder if there is any estimate, no matter how rough it may be, of the friction between interstellar dust and the projectile?

Comment: Why just dust? At the speeds where friction becomes relevant you also need to account for interstellar gas, and at highly relativistic speeds even the momentum of the photons has an effect.

Comment: different but related: [If a spacecraft travels at 10% c will it be destroyed by interstellar dust and particles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53929/12102)

Answer (score 5):

At sufficiently high speeds, which you will need for an interstellar spacecraft, particles will just crash into the cross section and transfer all of their momentum.

$$F_{drag} = v^2 \rho A$$

Where $v$ is the velocity relative to the medium, $\rho$ is the density of the interstellar medium, and  $A$ is the cross section area of the spacecraft.

Comment: See further calculations and comments in answer(s) to [If a spacecraft travels at 10% c will it be destroyed by interstellar dust and particles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53929/12102)